# How to restrict Chrome to load only a specific website?

Tags: chrome-for-android

We want to allow accessing our web based ERP and nothing else.

I tried  Surefox - but it does not honour target="_blank" in my anchor tags (basically it works as a one window/tab only browser ). Our Web based ERP uses a lot of popup windows.

How do I lockdown Chrome on Android to open only one website in the URL bar?

Comment: Surefox seems to suit my needs, so upvoted for being useful :) As for your case, I know this will sound completely off of what you're trying to achieve, but is the ERP yours like in developed by your company or yours as in what the company uses? 'Cause if you've developed it and are still using popups, I wouldn't recommend that, popups are outdated

Comment: It requires development of a WebView application that restricts loading third-party content.